# Android path seeking algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

## Context

I am trying to develop a simple 2D game where some "zombies" are going to chase me.

My idea to calculate the paths was the following (X = path not usable):

```
[4] [4] [X] [1] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[3] [X] [X] [0] [1] [X] [X] [X] [5]
[3] [2] [1] [1] [1] [X] [3] [4] [5]
[3] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [3] [4] [5]
```

Starting from 0, give the positions arround it 1 value, to those close to 1, give 2 value, etc. This way I just need to search for an lower index to know the quickest way to reach 0.

## Questions

**(1)** I don't know if this algorithm has a name so I could not really find information about it.

**(2)** The most optimal solution/algorithm/flow to calculate this

**(3)** In my mobile, the game screen has 1700 x 1440 resolution, so my code takes 15 seconds. I crated a final value to scale everything down and lower the matrix size, however, stil takes a lot, literally unplayable.

**(4)** Are there other needs ? Maybe adding threads ? I don't know if would that work though ...

## My code *(debug code deleted)*

### Code

```java
private void expandAllFrom(int x, int y){ // x and y already scalled down
    nodes = new ArrayList<Point>(); // "nodes" is a global variable //
    nodes.add(new Point(x, y));

    while ( nodes.size() > 0 ){
        Point p = nodes.remove(0);
        expand(p.x, p.y);
    }
}

private void expand(int x, int y){
    int limXMin = x - 1, limXMax = x + 1, limYMin = y - 1, limYMax = y + 1;
    int value = map[x][y];

    // Check limits of screen
    if ( limXMin < 0 ) limXMin = 0;
    if ( limXMax > SCREEN_X_DIV - 1) limXMax = SCREEN_X_DIV - 1;

    if ( limYMin < 0 ) limYMin = 0;
    if ( limYMax > SCREEN_Y_DIV - 1) limYMax = SCREEN_Y_DIV - 1;

    for (int i = limXMin; i <= limXMax; i++){
        for (int j = limYMin; j <= limYMax; j++){
            if ( map[i][j] == 0 ) {
                if ( i != x || j != y ){
                    nodes.add(new Point(i, j));
                    map[i][j] = value + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

I use a FIFO list. I add the nodes in there, for example, the flow would be something like:

```
(1) Add 0 position to expand node list.
(2) Expand 0 by setting 1 values arround it. Then add them to expand node list.
(2) Expand 1 by setting 2 values arround it. Then add them to expand node list.
(...)
(X) Expand 2 by setting 3 values arround it. Then add them to expand node list.
(Y) Expand 3 by setting 4 values arround it. Then add them to expand node list.
(...)
```

Comment: Sounds like A* (A-start)

Comment: Is your map randomized?

Comment: Btw, a ```Queue``` is usually a better fit for a FIFO list. For instance, a ```LinkedList```

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks, I will search about it. Regarding randomization, I don't really know what you mean. It somehow represents my game board, with objects blocking the path and stuff. Also, isn't an ArrayList ordered ?

Comment: Yes it is, but the way it is implemented, all the elements have to be shifted when you remove the first one, a ```LinkedList``` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @JornVernee Oh ! Much more efficient, I see. That may speed it up a little bit, thanks !

Comment: About the randomization, what I mean is, are the levels pre-made? Or are they generated every time?

Comment: @JornVernee They are not static. They change while playing since the player can block some paths to gain time. Also, since there will be many zombies, I need the map with the indexes, and then just check for every zombie the closer lower index.

Comment: You are not doing A*, technically you are doing Dijkstra's algorithm (also known as BFS, Breadth-first search) to every point on the map. How many zombies do you have? If not too many, you'd be better off with an algorithm which does a search for each zombie using some heuristic A*-type search. Have a look at https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/ to see how these work.

Comment: @BKE The amount will vary. I will increase them on each lvl. I guess, up to 30 maybe ? Is it worth/needed using heuristics ?

Comment: Definitely, it is madness to search through all of the map every time, if you only actually need directions for 30 points out of millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, what you do is called [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which is a special case of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Well done for finding it out for yourself!

The problem is, that the time complexity of BFS is `O(V+E)`, where `V` is the number of nodes, `E` is the number of edges. In your case, it will be in the order of the size of the map, depending on the sparsity of the map (that is, how many X-es there are). That is in any case in the order of millions for a map of size 1700x1440.

If the number of zombies is not too big, it would be much faster to calculate the shortest path for each zombie one by one (you could still share and re-use the expanded nodes between the zombies), using variations of BFS with heuristics. For example, [jump point search](https://harablog.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/jump-point-search/) is optimized for uniform cost mazes (jump point search is a special case of the [A-star algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)).

The idea there is to take a start point (a zombie's position) and an end point (the player's position), and to calculate the shortest path between them, expand the nodes which are closer to the destination first. Closer here means that the approximated distance to the endpoint is less. The distance to the reached nodes is known, and A star will choose the node where the sum of the distance from the start to the node, plus the approximated distance from the node to the end is the smallest. Since you allow diagonal moves, the distance approximation can not be the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), nor Eucledian distance, as the approximation has to be a lower bound to the real distance. You could take eg. max(│x-x'│, │y-y'│). Jump point search improves this further by taking advantage of the maze structure of the map, to exclude further nodes.

[This site](https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/) animates several such algorithms so you can get a feel how these work.

The nice thing about this approach is that you would not search through the whole map, only a small fraction of it which lies between the zombie and the player. This could already be orders of magnitude faster than any full scale BFS algorithm. To show how dramatic the speedup can be, have a look at the following images. Only the marked nodes are explored by the search:

[image: A star search]
[image: jump point search]

Another advantage is, that you could compromise between running time and the 'cleverness' of the zombies. All you have to do is not run such an algorithm all the way to the end point. You can stop after a pre-defined number of steps and get just an approximation for the beginning of the path (by looking at the shortest path between the start point and the most promising node to expand next). So depending on how much time you have for the calculation, you could have optimal or less optimal zombies.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. The A*  tries to expand the one with the lowest Manhattan distance ? (Manhattan distance = ( |X1-X0| + |Y1-Y0| )). Would there be any impact in using Euclidean distance (except for the time for the calculus ) ?

Comment: The distance to the reached nodes is already known. A* expands one of the reached nodes for which (distance from start) + (approximate distance to the end node) is minimal. I edited my answer because I realized you allow diagonal steps, so you can't use strictly manhattan distance, because the approximation needs to be a lower bound on the distance for A* to work. Eucledian distance does not work either in this sense. What would work is max(│x-x'│,│y-y'│) which gives you the minimum number of steps on an empty map.

Comment: Do you know of any easy implementation that I could use ?

Comment: I don't know of anything you could use out of the box. It is difficult because every project has its own representation of the world. There are many implementations out there you could adapt, eg. this: https://github.com/ClintFMullins/JumpPointSearch-Java

Comment: I have been thinking. Maybe I could use A*/JumpPointSearch depending on the amount of blocked positions. Would you do that ? Also, when does each of these shine more ? When is one better than the other ? Thanks.

Comment: JPS will be always better in a grid setting. A* is more general and can be applied to a wider range of problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is just **[breadth-first search (BFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)**, used to find the single-source shortest path. The numbers you want to calculate correspond exactly to the *level* in which each grid cell is located. The nice thing is that with a proper implementation of BFS, you don't need the numbers. Just start the BFS procedure at the player's location, then let each zombie step towards the *parent-pointer* of the cell they are currently in.

Comment: Wow, nice approach. That must be much more efficient that my code. This is how I plan to do it. First, create the matrix and add the zombie positions on it. Then, start expanding, when a position is occupied by a zombie move it to my previous position. Would that be correct ? Any tips ?

Comment: @UDKOX: you could do it that way, or you can just make a grid, do the BFS, then each zombie looks up its position in the grid and follows the parent-pointer.

Comment: That was my first idea. However, calculating all levels, when I only have a few zombies, is a waste of resources. So, I think I will try what I said above, but who knows, I stil gotta read the other comments.

Comment: @UDKOX: the first question I'd ask myself is: do you need a grid cell per pixel? This seems like a lot more precision than you'd need for simple seeking behaviour.

Comment: True. I scaled it down as I explained in the post, nevertheless, still so much work, even if there is only 1 zombie. I think I will give Jump Point Search a go.

Comment: @UDKOX: performance is going to depend on the exact situation. If you have very many zombies and/or many blocked positions, an algorithm that calculates a single path will suffer. The nice thing about BFS is that it would always take the same amount of time, regardless of the number/location of zombies or the player's location. The downside is that BFS doesn't scale well with few zombies in a large, open environment.